# using .htaccess redirect specific URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

how to redirect the website like this :

```
www.old.com/test.php -> www.new.com/test.php
```

but enter other links to `www.new.com/`

```
www.new.com/test1.php -> www.old.com/test1.php
www.new.com/test2.php -> www.old.com/test2.php
www.new.com/test3.php -> www.old.com/test3.php
```

How about if the file names are not in sequence, like this:

```
www.new.com/home.php -> www.old.com/aiej.php
www.new.com/contactus.php -> www.old.com/contact.php
www.new.com/aboutus.php -> www.old.com/aboutus.php
www.new.com/msdv.php -> www.old.com/msdv.php
```

only `test.php` will redirect to `www.new.com/`, others redirect back to `www.old.com`

I prefer to use `.htaccess` file. any suggestion?

Comment: You have to manually define the filenames to redirect to old site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rules in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect test.php to new
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(test)\.php$ http://www.new.com/$1.php [R=301,L]

# Redirect test* to old
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.new\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test(.+)\.php$ http://www.old.com/test$1.php [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.new.com$
RewriteRule ^test(1|2|3)\.php$ http://www.old.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com$
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ http://www.new.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```