# HTML Single-Page, Rooting/Linking to Subpage

Tags: html, redirect, root

I am very new to programming and I tried to build a single pager as a landing page for our small company. jQuery and Bootstrap libraries are installed, since I have some parallax elements. Now, I have different subcategories like:

```
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#faq">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#google_map">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#footer">Impressum</a></li>
```

It all works well. Page jumps well and smooth to different categories. So I made an actual flyer on paper, telling our customers to visit our FAQ, this looks like: go the hell to www.example.com/faq

But that is not working at all. 404 Site appears. It works when writing www.example.com/#faq. But that's not what's written on the flyer which is already printed. Now I am looking for a solution to make www.example.com/faq work. This should lead the costumer directly to the certain subcategorie on the single page.

I would be very greatful for hints :). Thanks a lot in advance!

Best

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution would be to set up some redirects in your .htaccess file on the server.

Countless people have asked how to do this, so I won't post it again here, but you can check this question out:
[using .htaccess redirect specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294718/using-htaccess-redirect-specific-url)

Or just do a google search on ".htaccess redirect".

Comment: Thanks Relevart! I created a htaccess file and tried different variations of code, but I always fail. My actual code looks like `RewriteEngine On
Redirect index.html/#faq http://www.example.de/faq` - still the same 404